# Reading file in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

i have a problem reading file in java:
i have a file made like this for example:

```
2,3
2
5
2
3
4
```

Where the first line represent the length of 2 array A and B and the other are the element of each array so : A[2,5] B[2,3,4]. I can read this input and save into two array

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        int A[] = null;
        int B[] = null;
        //int C[] = null;
        //int k = 0;
        try {
// Open the file that is the first
// command line parameter
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine = br.readLine(); // step 1

            if (strLine != null) {
                String[] delims = strLine.split(","); // step 2 split first line

// step 3 initialization array A and B
                A = new int[Integer.parseInt(delims[0])];
                B = new int[Integer.parseInt(delims[1])];
                //C = new int[Integer.parseInt(delims[2])]; //PROBLEMA SE NON CE K DA ERRORE RISOLVERE
                //k = 0;
                //k = C.length;


// step 4 Load A element from file input
                for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
                    A[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

// step 5 load B element form file input
                for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++)
                    B[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                br.close();
            }// step 6
        } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
//Sort Array with MergeSort

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(B));
```

But my problem is that the input may have in the first line another element k that i have to save.

```
2,3,5
2
5
2
3
4
```

and A[2,5] B[2,3,4] and i want to save  k = 5 but i don't know i to do. The problem is that K may not be in the input.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @ user1841492 : you may  delete the question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42265/how-can-i-delete-my-question

Comment: Please don't vandalize your questions.  Why did you undelete the post just to remove the question?  If you want to delete your post now, you'll have to have to flag it for a moderator.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream for text.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but if you want to save the third element on the first line just check the lenght of your array `delims[]`.

```
String[] delims = strLine.split(",");
if (delims.length > 2) {
  K = delims[2]
}
```

If there is more than two elements in the array then you save the third one (arrays start at 0).

Sorry if I didn't answered your question. You can comment if you want further precisions.

Comment: i'm sorry for bad english.. by the way thank you very much.. i try this way

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of the `delims` array.

```
int length = delims.length;
int k=0,a =0, b=0;

if (length == 3) {
  k = Integer.parseInt(delims[2]);
} 
  a = Integer.parseInt(delims[0]);
  b = Integer.parseInt(delims[1]);

A = new int[a];
B = new int[b];
```

OR

```
int k = delims.length == 3 ? Integer.parseInt(delims[2]) : 0;
```

Thanks

Comment: Well you still need to create those arrays is the first line has 3 elements. At least that's my understanding of the problem. You should put the instanciation of the arrays out of the else statement

Comment: correct :). thanks.. I'm correcting the code.